# edit parameter with htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

Some of the URL's have the parameter `?content_only=1` on the single product pages within `PrestaShop`. I would like to redirect these parameters to `?content_only=0`.

The URL structure looks like this:
https://www.onlineruitershop.nl/paardendekens/3953-esperia-two-fleece-deken.html?content_only=1
This should change to https://www.onlineruitershop.nl/paardendekens/3953-esperia-two-fleece-deken.html?content_only=0

After the first `/` are the categories and after the second `/` is the name and ID of the product. This should stay unaffected.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)content_only=1(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1content_only=0%2 [L,R=301]
```

[Here is the result](http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=42c5f360-948d-590a-b50c-c78034bbbb4f)